# Access browser thats open in another profile

Tags: firefox-addon, user-profile

I want to iterate over all windows that are open in all profiles. I can iterate over a single profile with this code (pasteable in scratchpad)

```
var me = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null);
let DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator(null);
while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
    let aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
    me.alert(aDOMWindow);
}
```

Comment: Im doing some research and I can't figure this out and I'm worried that it might not be possible. So I'm thinking of another method, to monitor a file. Ill ask in another topic how to observe and get notification when a file is modified.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible directly so you're right to look at alternatives such as monitoring a file. In more general terms you're trying to implement an IPC mechanism so you might be interested in reading around that subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: Ah thanks for that link man. I didn't know IPC was a thing. FF doesnt have a file watcher yet, do you know of any recommend method?

Answer (score 0):

Since running multiple instances of Firefox locally presupposes `-no-remote`, I don't think it's possible to establish a connection.

Comment: Ah dang. Thanks paa, can you please help me with how to monitor a file for change. I think I'll have each profile monitor a file, and then when it detects certain changes it will do certain things.